# maximize $x^T$Ax given one norm of x is 1 ($||x||$=1) x is a colomn vector

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

maximize $x^T$Ax given one norm of x is 1 ($||x||$=1), A is n$\times$n symmetric matrix, x$\in$$R^n$

Comment: What's the two one norm of x?

Comment: I have fixed that

Comment: Is $A$ positive semi definite?

Comment: It is not clear to me that there is a closed form solution for this without more constraints on $A$.